# Systematic approach to deriving equations of collective field theory to any order

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, gauge-theory, research-level

The collective field theory (see [nLab](http://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/collective+field+theory) for a list of main historical references) which came up as a generalization of the Bohm-Pines method in treating plasma oscillations often used in the study of large N asymptotics (e.g. of matrix models). I have seen few cases where the equations for collective fields are derived; the equations are obtained using approximations and look more systematically understood by other methods than those available at the dawn of collective field theory (i.e. since the works of Sakita and Jevicki).

Is there now a systematic method to derive collective field theory equations to any order in 1/N ? Also if the Yaffe's methods concerning coherent state methods in large N asymptotics are ever used in collective field theory? The subject looks interesting for doing some work (I have some background in coherent state techniques), but I do not know what the current state of advance is.

EDIT: added a bounty to renew interest.

Comment: I dont know if this could help or if it's even relevant but page 17 here http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9909037.pdf and http://archive.org/stream/arxiv-gr-qc9902064/gr-qc9902064_djvu.txt Let me know if these are useful or relevant. I am just a beginner.

Comment: I would suggest this [book](https://inspirehep.net/record/1277291/files/MCook_MSc.pdf) I think pages 29-30 offer some answers.